# Rails 3.1 - quick rewrite on deprecated query needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this:

```
Product.find(:all, :conditions => ['release_date >=? AND release_date <=?', @start, @start + @weeks.weeks], :order => "initial_stock DESC")
```

I understand conditions is now deprecated. This works fine locally but when I upload to heroku the order doesn't work, so probably best I rewite right? Problem is each thing i've tried throws an error. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work with `.where` and `.order`?

Comment: Stay tuned! Choose squeel! https://github.com/ernie/squeel and http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Product.where("release_date >= ? AND release_date <= ?", @start, @start + @weeks.weeks).order("initial_stock DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is used across the app I generally like to create a scope on the model for it.  I haven't tested this code but here's what I would do:

```
# scope on Product.rb
scope :by_release_date, lambda { |date| where("release_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day) }


# query anywhere in app
Product.by_release_date('2012-06-11 00:00:00').order('initial_stock DESC')
```

Comment: Dang Holger you're fast.  You edited my post before I hit the save-on-edit button!  Thanks!